# Permanently mark goal ... in pom.xml as ignored

Tags: java, m2e

I have a web project in eclipse using m2e. I had an error about a missing artifact in pom.xml and I clicked Permanently mark goal ... in pom.xml as ignored. What happened was it no longer copies the jar files from my repository. How do I undo this action. Don't know what configuration file or settings file was changed when I did that

Comment: It added an m2e item to your POM that you can see easily, and it only changes behavior in eclipse, not anywhere else.

Comment: It also affected other projects so I assumed the change was not in the POM of the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using m2e v1.1.  In this version, you can choose which pom in the hierarchy gets marked as having its lifecycle mapping ignored.  If it's not in the pom of the current project, it will be a pom in one of the parent projects.  Here is a good explanation of what is happening:

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

So you can do a file search for the term `pluginManagement` in all your pom.xml files in your workspace and you will find what you are looking for.